# php ini settings not working as expected

Tags: php, .htaccess, ini

I have a form that submited 3500 fields via a POST. This used to work with a few `ini_set();` defined but since having the server rebuilt to include `suhosin` it no longer works.

I've made these additions into the .htaccess to rectify this and make it work.

```
php_value suhosin.perdir pr
php_value max_execution_time 600
php_value max_input_vars 6000
php_value max_input_time 300
php_value post_max_size 320M
php_value suhosin.post.max_vars 6000
php_value suhosin.request.max_vars 6000
```

The values are higher than whats needed as this can be built upon by the client in the CMS, and may be needed in the future.

These can be seen to have an affect when using `phpinfo();` but the form still only posts a certain amount of fields.

What is it i'm missing? I've trawlled stack overflow and it appears i've done everything i need to.

Comment: Why would anyone fill in 3500 form fields?

Comment: @Cyclone You've never joined a consumer panel, have you?

Comment: @Cyclone Its eCommerce management. There's different lengths, widths, colours and thicknesses of the same product, all with their own prices and product codes. the prices dont have an incremental pattern either so each set of options has its own set of fields. I know it can be built in a better way, but this is a legacy website of ours and currently just need to make it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@carbontwelve There is a limit set on Apache mod_security for SecRequestBodyNoFilesLimit which was set to 128KB. This was a recent change made by our hosting provider to improve security. I got them to change it and BOOM, it worked like it used to.

Answer (score 0):

It could be that that your PHP installation does not allow modification of the Suhosin Post variables on a per directory basis.

If you wish to update Suhosin ini settings on a per directory basis via .htaccess then you need to add `suhosin.perdir = "p"` to your php.ini

Comment: Thanks for the response, however, i've already had that changed by our hosting suppliers before posting this, because i thought this was the issue aswell.

Comment: @Hazonko if you do find the right answer, please do share it; I would be interested in finding out the cause.

Comment: I've just posted the answer from my own investigations. spent about 10 hourse sifting through it all!